TuneD Modifying `base_slice_ns` On Ubuntu, Kernel Release `6.8.0-50-generic`
Since the 6.8.0-50-generic kernel release, /sys/kernel/dubug/sched/base_slice_ns has replaced /proc/sys/kernel/sched_min_granularity_ns. I am trying to modify base_slice_ns from a tuned.conf. Is this possible with the /sys/kernel/debug directory requiring root permissions and not able to use sysctl?
tuned.conf:
[main]
summary=Custom profile example, trying to modify `base_slice_ns`.
include=latency-performance

[sysctl]
kernel.debug.sched.base_slice_ns=1000000

Error in /var/log/tuned/tuned.log: 
ERROR    tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: Failed to read sysctl parameter 'kernel.debug.sched.base_slice_ns', the parameter does not exist
